# Saucelabs - intercept Android/iOS app HTTP(S) traffic

Tags: saucelabs

Is it possible with Saucelabs to intercept mobile HTTP(S) traffic? I want to verify that a specific set of requests are executed by an iOS and Android app. I'm not looking to modify the requests, just checking for execution. And this has to be done automatically, in CI, without any manual intervention. Thanks!

Comment: Are these requests against a 3rd party server or one you own?  Is the server public-facing, or are you using something like Sauce Connect?

Comment: Yes, it's a 3rd party server, more specifically some data analytics requests. I can intercept these requests using a proxy, and verify them, but I was also looking into a potential Saucelabs solution. Don't have hands on experience with SL at this point and don't know it's limitations.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, using a proxy is probably the best option.

If you were doing desktop tests, you could use Extended Debugging to capture a HAR file, then download it after the test and check the right calls were made.  Unfortunately, at the time of writing, Extended Debugging is only supported for Desktop.